# Конвертировать string в const char

Tags: c++

Как можно конвертировать строку string в const char? Нужно передать его в функцию `open` как имя файла.
Пример кода:

```
string A[] = {"name1", "name2", "name3"};
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  if(open(A[i],O_CREAT) == -1)
     {
       printf("create error \n");
       return 1;
     }
}
```

Comment: У класса `string` есть метод `c_str()`

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Спасибо, то что надо

Comment: Возможно вместо `open` подойдет `std::fstream`, который знает про `std::string` (≥с++11) (и умеет закрывать файл в деструкторе)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, так было бы проще :)

```
const char* A[] = {"name1", "name2", "name3"};
```

Какой смысл переводить строковый литерал в `string`, а потом назад?

Но если очень нужно, то -

```
open(A[i].c_str(),...
```